# How to scale figure down to a particular size in inches in matplotlib

Tags: plot, matplotlib

Suppose I prepare a PDF figure in matplotlib and let us say I have specified the original dimensions of the figure to be 10x10 inches. Would it be possible to produce essentially the same figure, but scaled down to 7x7in (so that all the fonts/point sizes, etc, would scale down appropriately)?

I do understand that I can open my 10x10 file in a vector graphics editor and perform the rescaling, but I was interested whether there is some simple switch that would do this directly from matplotlib.

Answer (score 3):

Use `set_size_inches`, like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

fig.set_size_inches([10,10])
ax.plot([1,3,2],[2,2,2],'ro-')
plt.savefig('10x10.png')

fig.set_size_inches([4,4])
plt.savefig('4x4.png')
```

Comment: set_size_inches is equivalent to simply providing figure size to the figure command. It does not "scale down" the figure, but rather changes the size of the plot area. In fact so far I have been using this figure size setting to obtain the desired "font size, point size, etc to figure size ratio". The only problem is that the resulting PDF is not of the same print size that I'd prefer and my question is whether it is possible to affect the print size somehow. I tried the dpi setting, but it does not seem to work. Maybe there's something else?

Comment: @KT: To the best of my knowledge, I don't think there's a way around looping over the plot elements then.